# MVC JQuery/AJAX How to send array to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to send an array from my view to controller using Jquery/Ajax.
I have a table with a list of assigned employees and a different table for available employees.

When the user clicks on a button in the available employees table it adds it to my newEmpArray array and colors the row green. This is working.

But I don't know how to send it through to the controller and parse it for use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

VIEW CODE:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready!");

        var newEmpArray = [];

        $(".AddEmp").on("click", function () {

            $(this).parents("tr").css("background-color", "green");
            var empID = parseInt($(this).parent().siblings().first().text());
            newEmpArray.push(empID);
            console.log(empID);

        });

        $("#ShowEmp").on("click", function () {

            jQuery.each(newEmpArray, function (index, id) {
                console.log("ID: " + newEmpArray[index]);
            });

        });

        $("form#frm").on("submit", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            let obj = {
                id: newEmpArray
            };

            $.ajax({

                url: "@Url.Action("AddEmployee")",
                method: "GET",
                data: { 
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj)
                }


            });


        });
    });



</script>
```

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
public ActionResult AddEmployee(string data)
        {
            JObject parsedData = JObject.Parse(data);

            char[] empIDS = parsedData["id"].ToString().ToArray();

            return RedirectToAction("ViewEmployees");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

View Code:

```
$("form#frm").on("submit", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({

                url: "@Url.Action("AddEmployee")",
                method: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                data: { 'ids': newEmpArray }
                    
            });


        });
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult AddEmployee(int[] ids)
        {
            int[] empArray = (ids);

            

            return RedirectToAction("ViewEmployees");
        }
```